# Render same endpoints but in different subdomain in swagger nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

I have the same endpoints but work in different subdomain. Let's imagine I have **login** endpoint in *http://admin.localhost:3000* and  *http://localhost:3000* and I want to render them in swagger. I have used ApiTags decorator to tag and used other needed decorators for swagger.

[image: controller]

And the same way for other controllers for other subdomains.

But, swagger renders only the last tagged endpoint.

[image: result on swagger]

But, I want swagger to render all available endpoints with different subdomains.

How can it be solved?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger generates docs for a single host at a time and that host is your server host. Nevertheless it supported multiple endpoints documentation for the same controller method. If that's not want you're out for try the followings:

*Note: For your request to be captured by a server the host most has been resolved.*

**1. Deployment:** Built your server app and deploy it to domain A, then use your DNS provider to redirect all request from domain B to domain A. Another ways is to deploy your app to both subdomains.

**2. Dissociate Apps:** Build two apps such that they'll be hosted on you separate domains. I recommend using [Nx](https://nx.dev) for better workspace configuration allowing you create a custom `Auth` lib reusable in all projects of your [Nx workspace](https://nx.dev)